# How to get ASP.NET Core to crash instead of returning an error response in Visual Studio 2019 when Debugging?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

Right now, when something crashes in some service after a request, the error is just sent to the response body.

However, for debugging purposes, I would like Visual Studio 2019 to actually pause on the crash and highlight the line, i.e:

[image]

The above doesn't happen when something crashes in a controller when a request is sent. If I throw this from a controller method, what's returned is a 500 error and I have to check the stacktrace manually to find the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Debug - Windows - Exception Settings`

You can just check `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` or choose specific exceptions.